# comparing columns of different length in python

Tags: python, excel, compare, append

I have two excels file (concentration, discharge). Both with columns: A=Year, B=month, C=day, D= Concentration/Discharge. But different lengths. For discharge I have daily data in the last 30 years (a lot of rows), and for concentration, i have monthly data in some years.
What I need is an append list of Discharge and Concentration of same days. And then plot this values againts. But looking for the days where I have concentration data into the excel of discharge, manually...is sooo tedious- I have tried with python, but I dont know how to deal with different lenghts...Thanks :=)

```
import pandas as pd

concentration= pd.read_excel()

discharge= pd.read_excel()

a = concentration.iloc[:,3:4]
year_c= concentration.iloc[:,0]
year_d= discharge.iloc[:,0]
month_c=concentration.iloc[:,1]
month_d=discharge.iloc[:,1]
day_c= concentration.iloc[:,2]
day_d= discharge.iloc[:,2]

Q=[]
 for element in a:
   if  year_c ==  year_d and month_c == month_d and day_c == day_d: 
   Q.append(a)
```